# hostname resolving in in ubuntu server subnet

Tags: networking, dns

I am facing some problems in the network I am trying to set-up at home.

I have router to access the internet to which all the hosts are connected; one of the hosts I am mentioning is an Ubuntu server where I created a specific subnet to which I can connect other clients.

```
Internet
   |
Router
    Host1    
    Host2 (Ubuntu server)
        Host2-1
```

Everything is working pretty fine, all the hosts can talk each other. The only problem I am facing is resolving the hostname of the Host2-1 (the one in the Ubuntu server subnet).

I can access to it via it’s IP address thanks to the static routing I added in the Ubuntu server, but I can’t resolve it’s hostname.

The DNS server for the Ubuntu server subnet and the related clients (Host2-1 in this example) is the very same one of the router-host1-host2 network.

It seems that the Host2-1 name is not added to the DNS server of the main network.

How can I sort this issue out?

Thank you all in advance

P.S.: I know I could add the host names to the clients hosts file but I'd like to have something a bit more dynamnic

Comment: Are Host 1 nad Host 2 registered to your internal DNS? Do they dynamically register or use something like NETBIOS to find each other? If it is the latter that's why you can't resolve Host2-1.

Comment: Thanks for the kind feedback first of all! I don't have an internal DNS and this might me the problem right?

Comment: If you don't have one it's likely that those machines use NETBIOS or something similar to discover their neighbors and ask for their names. Usually those approaches run into issues if you have a broadcast border like a router.

Comment: Thanks Seth! I was forgetting to mention I have all ubuntu/linux clients in my network. I will try this out anyway